# CSS. Parent > Child1:hover. How to display Parent > Child2?

Tags: css

Hopefully the title of my question was clear enough.

Here's a really simple version of my CSS Combo Box. I think I'm just missing something minor and hope you can help with it. Basically I have a container Div, then I have a dropdown Div that holds the floated button on the right. Inside this dropdown Div I also have a Menu Div that is hidden until the user hovers the floated button Div.

I can get it to work by hovering over the dropdown Div since the menu Div is a child of it HOWEVER, I wanted to be able to hover over the button Div which is the first child of dropdown Div and display menu Div, which is the second child of dropdown div and not of button div.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">


#container {
position: relative;
background-color: #999999;
height: 31px;
width: 200px;
}

#container #dropdown {
background-color: #999999;
height: 31px;
width: 200px;
}

#container #dropdown #button {
float: right;
background: #555555 url('assets/img/ddw.png') no-repeat center;
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
margin-top: 3px;
margin-right: 3px;
}

#container #dropdown #button:hover #menu  {
display: block;
float: right;
background: #555555 url('assets/img/ddw.png') no-repeat center;
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
margin-top: 3px;
margin-right: 3px;

}

#container #dropdown #menu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #777777;
top: 32px;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
}


</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>index</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="dropdown">

<div id="button"></div>
<div id="menu">
Option 1
<br/>
Option 2
<br/>
Option 3
</div>
</div>



</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing your `div#menu` inside your `div#button`. Then, give `div#menu` the following properties: `position: relative`, `display: block`, and `top: 25px`. Give your `button` div an `overflow: hidden`. then, change your `#container #dropdown #button:hover #menu` selector to `#container #dropdown #button:hover`, and give it the following properties: `width: auto`, `height: auto`, `overflow: visible`. See this jsFiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kzEek/

Answer (score 2):

Since `#menu` comes after `#button`, you can use the adjacent sibling selector (`+`) instead of the descendant selector (space):

```
#container #dropdown #button:hover + #menu  {
display: block;
float: right;
background: #555555 url('assets/img/ddw.png') no-repeat center;
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
margin-top: 3px;
margin-right: 3px;

}
```

Comment: I just barely put this together. If you have better practice "DIV placement advice, please, by all means, feel free to suggest. Trying your stuff right now. Hang on. Bt the way, does using ( + ) make it CSS3?

Comment: Wow. What an incredibly simple solution. Thanks a lot man. By the way, if I switch "hover" to "active" is there a way to make it so once the user clicks it, the menu remains visible until he either clicks it again or clicks anywhere else on the page?

Comment: @Vini: You'll need a bit of JavaScript for that, as that's not how `:active` works.

Comment: Just a heads-up: the adjacent sibling selector won't work in IE6. If you're shooting for IE6 compatibility, see my solution below.